# Printing Arrays from Structs

Tags: c, struct

I've been stumped for a few hours on an exercise where I must use functions to build up an array inside a struct and print it. In my current program, it compiles but crashes upon running.

```
#define LIM 10

typedef char letters[LIM];

typedef struct {
    int counter;
    letters words[LIM];
} foo;


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    foo apara;
    structtest(apara, LIM);
        print_struct(apara);

}

int structtest(foo *p, int limit){
    p->counter = 0;
    int i =0;
    for(i; i< limit ;i++){
        strcpy(p->words[p->counter], "x");
                //only filling arrays with 'x' as an example
        p->counter ++;
    }
    return;
```

I do believe it's due to my incorrect usage/combination of pointers. I've tried adjusting them, but either an 'incompatible types' error is produced, or the array is seemingly blank

```
}

void print_struct(foo p){
    printf(p.words);

}
```

I haven't made it successfully up to the print_struct stage, but I'm unsure whether p.words is the correct item to be calling. In the output, I would expect the function to return an array of x's.
I apologize in advance if I've made some sort of grievous "I should already know this" C mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also wouldn't pass the structure to `print_struct` because you are copying sizeof(foo) to the stack. Pass a pointer instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of structest() is declared as a pointer of type foo.

```
int structtest(foo *p, int limit)
```

In main, you are not passing a pointer to a foo variable, you are just passing a foo variable.

```
structtest(apara, LIM);
```

Try passing a pointer to a foo variable like this:

```
structtest(&apara, LIM);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_struct(foo p){
    printf(p.words);

}
```

> I haven't made it successfully up to the print_struct stage, but I'm
>   unsure whether p.words is the correct item to be calling. In the
>   output, I would expect the function to return an array of x's. I
>   apologize in advance if I've made some sort of grievous "I should
>   already know this" C mistake. Thanks for your help.

You can't send an array to printf, the way you can print arrays in other languages. You have to do the looping yourself:

```
void print_struct(foo paragraph)
{
   printf("counter: %d\n",paragraph.counter);
   for (int i = 0; i < paragraph.counter; i++)
   {
      printf("words[%d] %s\n",i,paragraph.words[i]);
   }
}
```

You should move the main() function to the bottom of your source code. Or, you will have to add function prototypes for any code defined below main, above main:

```
int structtest(foo *p, int limit);
....
main()
{
...
}
int structtest(foo *p, int limit)
{
...
}
```